# Multi image's resolution development with iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I want to develop a universal iOS app (IPhone3 & 4 & 5, iPade 1 & 2 & 3 & 4, iPad Mini). 
After several researches on Internet, I found the following results:

[image: results of the my search]

My questions are:

1- Are my results true?

2- Do I need the three image's resolution(because we have 3 aspect ratio) to developp one app for the different iOS devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`1`

Yes, Its true. You can find more details from [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) porvided by `Apple`.

`2`

Yes, Mainly we required these three type of Images also depends on your iOS project.

[Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1), 
[App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) and
[Launch Images.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

And also please review this [iOS Resolution Quick Reference](http://www.iosres.com/).

And as per you comment you can find the Icon resolution information for android from [Android Developer portal](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). And for window you can find from [Window Developer portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (Differ for window phone 7 and window phone 8). or for you more information when we create a project for `Window Phone` this will give you sample images you can replace according to there and you requirements.

Comment: thanks, Can you give me information about the ratio of images in android and windows phone app because I am developping with MonoGame to make cross platform app.